# Leaflet markers are not being displayed

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This code used to work, but I'm not sure what I changed, or what changed in Leaflet to break it, but no markers are showing. Data is coming back correctly, marker objects are being created, but no markers are being displayed. I'm at a loss here. Using 0.7.2. Let me show you the code...

```
  function getGameMarkers(){
 var center = map.getCenter();
 var zoo = map.getZoom();
 var bounds = map.getBounds();
 var min = bounds.getSouthWest().wrap();
 var max = bounds.getNorthEast().wrap();

 //console.log(bounds);
 //console.log(min);
 //console.log(max);

 $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "./ajax/markers.php", dataType: "json", data: "clat="+center.lat+"&clng="+center.lng+"&zoom="+zoo+"&minlat="+min.lat+"&minlng="+min.lng+"&maxlat="+max.lat+"&maxlng="+max.lng+cookiestr, 
  success: function(data){
        if (data.showmap == 1) {
           plotlist = data.map_data;    
           removeMarkers();
           //console.log(plotlist.length);

           for (i=0;i<plotlist.length;i++) {
                var iconic = String(plotlist[i].icon);
                var plotmark = new L.marker([plotlist[i].lat,plotlist[i].lng], {icon: L.icon({iconUrl: iconic, iconSize: [32, 32]}) }).bindPopup(plotlist[i].html);
                map.addLayer(plotmark);
                console.log(plotmark);
                console.log(plotlist[i]);
                plotlayers.push(plotmark);
            }

           $("#content").html(data.html);
        }else {
          $("#map_content").show(); 
          $("#map_content").html(data.main_content);
          $("#content").html(data.side_content);
        }
    } 
  });
```

}

Everything should be working just fine. The server returns the information correctly. There are always 13 items in the list (expected behavior), and I print the contents of plostlist[i] to the console as well as the plotmarker object.

Here is the output for plotlist[i]:

```
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
Object {lat: "41.564087", lng: "-73.023376", icon: "./img/avicon3.png", html: "<a href='#' onclick='getcon(8,107184863);'>viktor</a><br/><br/>Level: 2 / Energy: 3 "} (index):100
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
Object {lat: "40.944637", lng: "-73.671570", icon: "./img/avicon3.png", html: "<a href='#' onclick='getcon(8,116518883);'>gambatedhan</a><br/><br/>Level: 3 / Energy: 8 "} (index):100
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
Object {lat: "41.288128", lng: "-74.135742", icon: "./img/avicon2.png", html: "<a href='#' onclick='getcon(8,118454338);'>halil</a><br/><br/>Level: 1 / Energy: 8 "} (index):100
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
Object {lat: "40.857449", lng: "-74.039612", icon: "./img/avicon3.png", html: "<a href='#' onclick='getcon(8,120599464);'>KIM15</a><br/><br/>Level: 2 / Energy: 1 "} (index):100
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
Object {lat: "40.6687012", lng: "-73.9646988", icon: "./img/bicon2.png", html: "<a href='#' onclick='getcon(2, 157764); return false;' >Brooklyn Botanic Garden</a>"} (index):100
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
Object {lat: "40.7062111", lng: "-73.3062286", icon: "./img/ricon.png", html: "<a href='#' onclick='getcon(1, 114779); return false;' >West Islip</a>"} (index):100
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
Object {lat: "40.7625999", lng: "-73.4531784", icon: "./img/ricon.png", html: "<a href='#' onclick='getcon(1, 114526); return false;' >Old Bethpage</a>"} (index):100
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
Object {lat: "40.9381485", lng: "-73.8320770", icon: "./img/ricon.png", html: "<a href='#' onclick='getcon(1, 114063); return false;' >Bronxville</a>"} (index):100
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
```

Everything looks fine...now for plotmark output:

```
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
 (index):99
e {options: Object, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_events: Object, _popupHandlersAdded: true…}
```

Once again, looks fine.

So...

Here are my thoughts on what could be happening...either those lat/lng coordinates being returned are being deprecated or are being interpreted differently and they are off the map, or the layer isn't being displayed for some reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just verified that the lat/lng being returned were between min/max in the code, and they are. Tested out the markers in Google Maps, and they should be appearing within those coordinates. So there goes that theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the world was starting over again, and wrapping over itself. To fix this, worldCopyJump needs to be set to true in your map options.

Answer (score 2):

Add your own css...   It worked for me.. Include the below code in your css file.

```
  .leaflet-map-pane {
       z-index: 2 !important;
    }

    .leaflet-google-layer {
        z-index: 1 !important;
    }
```